# Split-view on iPad (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to make a Split View Controller in Portrait show the master pane initially (without having to swipe or press a button). Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the `displayMode` property?

Comment: @rmaddy I use the `displayMode` property to hide the master pane after the user taps a search result in portrait. Then, I reset it to `.automatic` so it doesn't stay hidden when the user switches to landscape. Perhaps, I need to set the `displayMode` to `.primaryOverlay` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the following code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryOverlay
```